# Any compatibility issues with NavBars and Panels?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm currently trying to use a panel within my html page. I currently have a NavBar to allow quick actions such as back a month, current date, etc. Looks fine but when I apply a panel the NavBar moves to the very bottom of the page, like a footer. I don't want this.

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1><div id='title'></div></h1>
    <a data-icon="gear" href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
 </div> 
 <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-icon-alt">
    <ul>
    <li><a onClick="changedate('prevmo')" data-icon="arrow-l">Back a Month</a></li>
    <li><a onClick="sync()" class="ui-icon-alt" data-icon="refresh">Sync</a></li>
    <li><a onClick="changedate('return')" data-icon="home">Current Date</a></li>
    <li><a onClick="checkEonline()" class="ui-icon-alt"data-icon="plus">New Event</a></li>
    <li><a onClick="changedate('nextmo')" data-icon="arrow-r">Forward a month</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div role="main" class="ui-content">
</div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

**Panel Code**

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
    <a href="#mypanel" data-rel="close">Close panel</a>
</div><!-- /panel -->
```

It doesn't matter where I place this panel code, it will move the NavBar to the bottom of the page. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your navbar is not inside the header.
Change markup to:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1><div id='title'></div></h1>
    <a data-icon="gear" href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
    <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-icon-alt">
        <ul>
            <li><a onClick="changedate('prevmo')" data-icon="arrow-l">Back a Month</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="sync()" class="ui-icon-alt" data-icon="refresh">Sync</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="changedate('return')" data-icon="home">Current Date</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="checkEonline()" class="ui-icon-alt"data-icon="plus">New Event</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="changedate('nextmo')" data-icon="arrow-r">Forward a month</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> 
 <!-- /header -->
```